# powershell assign one row from document to variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, quest

I'm using cmdlet Get-QADUser (by Quest software) to list domain users from Active Directory. The output is several hundreds of rows with domain names and email addresses. I need to select only those rows, where is email address and assign them to a separate variable.

This is part of $domain_names variable:

```
turbekova                                                   turbek@dock.com                                                       
senajova                                                    senaj@dock.com                                                       
mackova                                                                                                            
pukansky                                                    pukansky@dock.com                                                       
tiko                                                        tiko@dock.com                                                       
dvorska                                                                                                            
trescanska                                                  tresc@dock.com
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This show users with email using parameter of property you choose and wildcard:

```
 Get-QADUser -Email * | select samaccountname, email
```

Comment: Thank you, Christian, this works excellently. But I have last question: Is it possible to check if the email addresses have e.g. 20 characters? I've tried it with Where-Object {$_.email.Count -eq 20}, but this isn't working..

Answer (score 2):

You can filter with `Where-Object`:

```
$hasEmail = Get-QADUser | Where-Object { $_.Email }
```

Or whatever the column is named. You chose to not include the property names in your copied output.